# I want to know about p5js

Tags: p5.js

```js
let size = 10;
let erasesize = 10;
let gamemode = 0;
let l = [];  
function setup() {
 createCanvas(400, 400); 
    }

function draw() {
   l[0] = new k;
 background(0,10);
   noStroke();  
 if(keyIsDown(UP_ARROW)){
   gamemode = 1;    
   }   
  if(gamemode === 1){
   l[0].draw();
   size += 7;
}
   if(size > 100){
   push();
   fill(0);
   ellipse(200,200,erasesize);
   erasesize += 9;    
   pop();
   }
if(size > 400){
   size = 0;
   gamemode = 0;
   erasesize = 0;
}    
}
class k{
   constructor(){
       this.x = 200;
       this.y = 200;
       this.size = size;
   }
   draw(){
       push();
       fill(random(255),random(255),random(255));
       ellipse(this.x,this.y,this.size);
       pop();
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

sorry,I can use English just a little.
I use this code to draw rainbow circle.
but I cant draw executes as much as the up arrow key is pressed.
my question is: How should I do to executes as much as the up arrow key is pressed?

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you want the sketch to do. I edited the code and turned it into a runnable snippet.. with one small correction the "l" variable was not declared.. so with that correction it draws circles each time the up arrow is pressed.. if you can help me understand what you want I think we can help.

Comment: ..is the problem that the rainbow circles continue to draw if the arrow key is held down instead of drawing just once?

Comment: In other word....

Comment: I want to display many times(code is work, but if I use this code,display is reflected only once. press to display immediately)

Comment: or Do the processing in the class as soon as you press uparrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make pressing the arrow key determine the number of times the circles will display you can listen for `keyPressed` and increase a count when the key is `UP_ARROW`

In this snippet I have taken the general idea from your question but rewritten so that there is a separation between drawing logic and control logic.

I also added the `u' for up key to the listener as the arrow key can cause scrolling.

```js
let size = 10;
let eraseSize = 10; 
let rainbowCount = 0;
let rainbow = 0;
function setup() {
   createCanvas(400, 400);
   rainbow = new Rainbow(); 
}

function keyPressed() {
  // listen for up arrow or u key presses
   if (keyCode === UP_ARROW || 
       keyCode === 85) {
      rainbowCount+=1;
  }
}

function draw() {
   background(0,10);
   noStroke();  
  
  if(rainbowCount > 0){
   size += 7;
   rainbow.setSize(size);
   rainbow.setEraseSize(eraseSize);
   rainbow.draw();  
  }

  if (size > 100){
    eraseSize += 9;
  }
  if(size > 400){
   size = 0;
   rainbowCount--;
   eraseSize = 0;
  }
}
class Rainbow{
   constructor(){
       this.x = 200;
       this.y = 200;
       this.size = 0;
       this.eraseSize = 0;
   }
   setSize(size){
     this.size = size;
   }
   setEraseSize(eraseSize){
     this.eraseSize = eraseSize;
   }
   draw(){
     push();
     fill(random(255),random(255),random(255));
     ellipse(this.x,this.y,this.size);
     pop();
    if(this.size > 100){
     push();
     fill(0);
     ellipse(200,200,this.eraseSize);  
     pop();
   }
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```